# Is there a way to play expansions in offline mode?

Tags: battlefield-2

As the title suggests, I am looking to see if there is a way to play the Battlefield 2 expansions with bots in offline mode.

Comment: BF2 have a offline mode?

Comment: @DrakaSAN Yes...it does...but its dead easy.

Comment: Still a good reason for me to try to get it, I m tired of BF3 badmins, and BF4 do not appeal to me anymore.

Comment: Well offline mode is great for when there is no internet connection available.  And @DrakaSAN Steam & Origin sell the collection for 20$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone told me over at the Steam community how to achieve this:

> Log into the game with an Offline Account, click Community, then click Custom Games, click the line that says Special Forces, then click the Activate button...it will restart the game in Special Forces single player mode.